# SQL - Add all previous columns and current column without lag and lead

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression, row-number

I got a table like

```
  ID      YEAR    VALUE  
  ----------------------
  1       2017    1
  1       2018    8
  1       2019    0
  1       2020    6
  1       2021    2
```

i'm trying to add all previous row VALUE column values to the current row VALUE column value and display a total. My result should be as follows:

```
  ID      YEAR    VALUE  TOTAL
  ----------------------------
  1       2017    1      1
  1       2018    8      9
  1       2019    0      9
  1       2020    6      15
  1       2021    2      17
```

i tried using join and row_number to get this but 2019 value of 0 is messing up.

```
 select *, row_number() over (partition by ID order by YEAR) as RN
 into #t1
 from tbl

 select 
    t1.VALUE + ISNULL(t2.VALUE, 0),
    t1.*
from #t1 as t1
left join #t1 as t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID and (t2.RN + 1) = t1.RN
```

the result that I'm getting with this query is:

```
  ID      YEAR    VALUE  TOTAL
  ----------------------------
  1       2017    1      1
  1       2018    8      9
  1       2019    0      8
  1       2020    6      6
  1       2021    2      8
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a solution similar to the one you tried:

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by ID order by YEAR) as RN
into #t1
from tablename;

select
  t.id, t.year, t.value, sum(#t1.value) TOTAL
from tablename t inner join #t1
on #t1.id = t.id and #t1.year <= t.year
group by t.id, t.year, t.value;
```

Or calculate the running total with a subquery:

```
select t.*,
  (select sum(value) from tablename where id = t.id and year <= t.year) TOTAL
from tablename t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0b020435f3dd29bd43338dea64747d19).
Results:

```
> id | year | value | TOTAL
> -: | ---: | ----: | ----:
>  1 | 2017 |     1 |     1
>  1 | 2018 |     8 |     9
>  1 | 2019 |     0 |     9
>  1 | 2020 |     6 |    15
>  1 | 2021 |     2 |    17
```

Answer (score 1):

You need window function :

```
select t.*, sum(t.[value]) over (partition by t.id order by t.[year]) as total
from #t1 t;
```

Comment: Can you see any issue with the syntax, "I'm getting Incorrect syntax near 'order'" error : select t.*, sum(t.VALUE) over(partition by t.ID order by t.YEAR) from #FINAL t

Comment: @JohnM this is because this was unavailable in sql server 2008. It was unavailable until 2012. Any chance of upgrading? 2008 end of life was last month.

Comment: I don't think there will be a upgrade in near future, any other solution for 2008? I just googled for window function to get cumulative sum which is what I want after I saw this answer. any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can do a running total in 2008 but it is painful to write and can be painfully slow as well.

Comment: I like this answer but it doesn't fit to my version but thanks for the quick reply